# how to check status of task inside downstream task in airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

we have one requirement where we want to take decision in downstream depending on status of upstream operator status. Depending on status of upstream operator(can be PythonOperator or BigQueryInsertJobOperator) we are going to decide action in downstream operator. most of the time our downstream operator is performing audit operation so in case of failure we want to fetch the error message too. to trigger this downstream operator we need to use trigger_rule='all_done', but I am not able to fetch the status and error message in downstream task. any one suggest best way to do this ?

Comment: I'm reading multiple things you're trying to achieve. Please clarify your question, asking one thing at a time. What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: how to pull error message in downstream task

Answer (score 0):

You should save the status and error message in an XCom and read both of them in your "audit" task.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html

Comment: pythonoperator is fine but if my BigQueryInsertJobOperator got failed then how to push its status to xcom